# Is there a more elegant way blanking out a sub-menu in XFCE?

Tags: xfce, menu

I am creating a login for my daughter under XFCE and I wanted to keep the all the top level folders/directories under application menu visible but to blank out the contents of those that would just clutter the place up and serve no purpose for her.  The image below is what I have managed to achieve however it feels like I have achieved it in an inelegant way.

[image: what it currently looks like]

**`.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu` (small part to illustrate the image above):**

```
<Menu>
    <Name>Development</Name>
    <Directory>xfce-development.directory</Directory>
    <Include>
<!--
        <Category>Development</Category>
-->
        <Filename>xfce4-empty-placeholder.desktop</Filename>
    </Include>
</Menu>
```

**`.local/share/applications/xfce4-empty-placeholder.desktop`:**

```
[Desktop Entry]                                                                                     
Version=1.0                                                                                         
Type=Application                                                                                    
Exec=                                                                                               
Icon=                                                                                               
Name=<empty>                                                                                        
Comment=place holder to allow empty submenus
```

I was hoping that the `Icon=` line would mean there was no icon.  I was wrong.

Initially I tried `Exec=/bin/false` which worked a treat (i.e. did nothing when you clicked on the menu entry) but then out of curiosity tried `Exec=` and found out it greyed out the whole of the menu entry including the icon.  I preferred this version and now I'm not bothered about the icon.

However is there a more elegant or approved way of doing this?

(PS ignore that `No applications found` at the bottom of the menu as I am currently working on where the logout entry has gone that was there 2 days ago)

Comment: Oooooo!  Not heard of MenuLibre.  Will have to have a look at that.  Ta @DKBose.  I had tried the infamous google for trying to find a menu editor but hit a brick wall.  
  
As to version: XFCE 4.10 on top of Kubuntu 14.04 currently through a remote session but ultimately to be used directly on the host

Comment: @DKBose unless I am missing something `NoDisplay` applies to `.desktop` files and if I use this in the only desktop file the menu uses then the entry for the submenu disappears completely as there are no menu entries to display in the submenu.  I want to keep the top level menu entry.  Also if it did work that would involve rather a lot of alterations to change every `.desktop` file for each submenu.